# Codeigniter SQL Server crud operations

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, crud

I am using Codeigniter with SQL Server. I have installed all SQL server drivers configured CI as below:

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:host=DESKTOP-PC\\MSSQLSERVER;dbname=crud',
'hostname' => 'DESKTOP-PC\MSSQLSERVER',
'username' => 'sa',
'password' => 'testpass',
'database' => 'crud',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => FALSE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

I want to do CRUD operations but CI queries are not operating with this. 
Using this query for insert:

```
$result = $this->db->insert('students', $post_data);
```

It prints last_query but it is not inserting details into the database. Can you please help me with this? Can you suggest me the solution for CRUD operations using CI and MSSQL with sqlsrv DB driver?